# Computing adjoint of operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to find $T^*$, when the kernel $K(x,y)$ satisfies $K(y,x)=\overline{K(x,y)}$ and for any real $a$, the operator

$$ (Tu)(x)=au(x)+i\int_0^1 K(x,y)u(y)dy$$

on $L^2([0,1])$.

In fact, $T$ is normal, but I have confused how to compute $T^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $ \langle T^{*}u, v \rangle =\int_0^{1} u(x)\overline {Tv (x)} dx=\overline {a} \langle u, v \rangle-i\int_0^{1} u(x) \int_0^{1} k(x,y) \overline {v(y)} dy dx$. Interchange the integrals on the right and express RHS in the form $\int_0^{1} \overline {v(y)} g(y)dy$. The conclusion then  is $T^{*}u=g$.